# Update section of column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I have a mySQL database containing information on pictures.

Now I would like to edit the title of the images, but using zenPhoto this would take days. So I was hoping that there is a way of mas updating using mySQL.

I want to replace the text in the title column from rows 105 to row 378 with 'New York 2007'

I have see something like  `UPDATE zp_images SET title = New York 2007` to update the entire column, but don't know about the rows.

Thanks in advance

Aled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps u...

```
update table_name set title ='New York 2007' where id >= 120 and id <= 460;
```

Comment: For some reason it says 0 rows affected and has not updated. the code i entered was 'update zp_images set title ='New York 2007' where id >= 105 and id <= 378;' Is there a way of displaying row numbers two, as i'm not sure if i'm entering the correct ones.

Comment: How be exporting to .sql or what? And instead of row numbers I can see that i have a column called ID and the items I want to edit is the title column for the info in rows (id number) 2478 to 2734.

Comment: check for record existence before update `select title from zp_images where id >=2478 and id <=2734`  , if record is exist then use update query `Update zp_images SET  title ='New York 2007' where id >= 2478 and id <= 2734`

Comment: it came up saying 'Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 257 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)' and showed the underneath.